# How to prevent packrat installs packages in system's library inside docker?

Tags: r, linux, docker

I have a shiny project using packrat. When I create a Rocker-shiny Docker container I put commands in Dockerfile in order to install packrat package and restore library. However, I see that packrat installs packages into system library (/usr/local/lib/R/...) instead private project library. If I enter in bash docker's console and I start a R session into project dir then reads .Rprofile file and packrat is installed and starts packages installation into private library. How I can get this from Dockerfile?

In my Dockerfile:

```
RUN cd /srv/shiny-server && \ R -e 'install.packages("packrat" , repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org"); packrat::restore()'
```

Install packages into /usr/local/lib/R... what is wrong.

However, if I enter into docker bash and start a R session into my project dir, it works fine:

```
docker exec -it test_app bash
cd /srv/shiny-server
R # start R session into project dir
Packrat is not installed in the local library -- attempting to bootstrap an installation...
> Installing packrat into project private library:
- "/srv/shiny-server/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3"
* installing *source* package ‘packrat’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (packrat)
> Attaching packrat
> Restoring library
Installing plyr (1.8.1) ... OK (built source)
```

Comment: If your project is dockerised, what’s the issue with installing stuff into the system library?

Comment: I do not know the reason but it does not install all the packages from packrat.lock file into the system library. For example, while docker container is bein created, I see how all packages are builded and installed OK but then some packages are missing and my app crashes.

Comment: To build on @KonradRudolph’s comment, usually you _do_ want to install things into the “system” paths in your Dockerfile: it saves a great deal of trouble with setting up environment variables and alternate paths.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and fixed the issue by restoring the packrat packages in my docker-compose file:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
...
command: [sh,-c, "sudo Rscript config/packrat_restore.R"]
...
```

**packrat_restore.R:**

```
packrat::init(
  infer.dependencies = FALSE,
  enter = TRUE,
  restart = FALSE)
packrat::restore()
```

As this workaround will always delay the startup of my containers in production, I will still try to fix the problem in the Dockerfile itself...